# Django Не подключается urls приложения в главном urls.py

Tags: python, django

Главный файл urls.py не подключает

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('shop/', include('shop.urls'))
]
```

Выдает вот это чудо:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\BMI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 600, in url_patterns
iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "D:\BMI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\BMI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "D:\BMI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
all_issues = checks.run_checks(
File "D:\BMI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
File "D:\BMI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
File "D:\BMI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
return check_method()
File "D:\BMI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 413, in check
messages.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
File "D:\BMI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
return check_method()
File "D:\BMI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 412, in check
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "D:\BMI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in **get**
res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "D:\BMI\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 607, in url_patterns
raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'shop.urls' from 'D:\sites\shopdvd\shop\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is proba
bly caused by a circular import.

Приложение есть в InstalledApps, файл urls в приложении shop также присутсвует

Comment: покажи содержимое `shop/urls.py`, может там отсутствует `urlpatterns`

Comment: Да, он пустой, но в уроке, который я смотрел все работало и с пустым файлом shop/urls.py, я проверю, спасибо!